# ThunderClient_How to validate Json file all keys thats expected to be returning into the response body

Tags: json, thunderclient

I'm using Thunder Client extension in VS code and trying to validate the JSON response body, Kind of array testing , Our test principle is to validate the JSON response body returning the correct property along with response.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "count": 4,
    "rows": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sam",
        "code": "E101",
        "description": "default"
      }
       {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ram",
        "code": "E102",
        "description": "default"
      }
       {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Sammy",
        "code": "E103",
        "description": "default"
      }
       {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Tom",
        "code": "E104",
        "description": "default"
      }
```

Below is the screenshot of the tests was trying to validate presence of all keys of arrays are present or not

[image]

I've tried below scenario to validate IDs exists in the JSON and it works however failed to validate all keys available in the entire JSON.

[image]